# Eclipse GEF - Locking ConnectionAnchors to positions on a Figure

Tags: eclipse-gef

Is there a method for locking connections in place when connecting to figures.  I am using connection anchors and have specified the vertical and horizontal offsets for the anchors in each figure.  After connection is established, if the figures are moved, then the position of the connection on the figure is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I hadn't modified the getTargetConnectionAnchor(ConnectionEditPart connEditPart) method to pass back the correct anchor, as I had with the getTargetConnectionAnchor(Request request) method.

Comment: If your problem is solved, you can (and should) accept your own answer btw :).